# How to make day value clickable in month view?

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a way to make the day of the month value clickable in the month view?

I would like it so when a user clicks on a day in the month, the fullCalendar would switch to the day view of that particular day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant changing to day-view when user clicks on a day-*number* in month view, please check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/AP9Ns/

Let me know if this helps.